# expected `&Arc<ProxyPool>`, found `&ProxyPool`

Tags: networking, rust, proxy, reference

I try to clone a reference from `&ProxyPool` to `&Arc<ProxyPool>` but im still getting an error, the type of the reference is still `&ProxyPool`.

```
pub struct ProxyPool {
    connections: Mutex<Vec<TcpStream>>,
    proxy_addresses: Arc<Vec<SocketAddr>>,
}
pub struct PooledConnection {
    stream: TcpStream,
    pool: Arc<ProxyPool>,
}

impl ProxyPool {
    async fn get_connection(&self) -> Result<PooledConnection> {
        loop {
            if let Some(conn) = {
                let mut connections = self.connections.lock().unwrap();
                connections.pop()
            } {
                return Ok(PooledConnection {
                    stream: conn,
                    pool: Arc::clone(self), // converting &ProxyPool to Arc<ProxyPool>
                });
            }
            // If no connection is available, wait a bit and try again.
            tokio::time::sleep(Duration::from_millis(100)).await;
        }
    }

    fn return_connection(&self, conn: TcpStream) {
        let mut connections = self.connections.lock().unwrap();
        connections.push(conn);
    }

    fn get_random_proxy_address(&self) -> SocketAddr {
        let idx = rand::random::<usize>() % self.proxy_addresses.len();
        self.proxy_addresses[idx]
    }
}
```

any ideas why this is happen?

```
204 |                     pool: Arc::clone(self), // Convert &ProxyPool to Arc<ProxyPool>
    |                           ---------- ^^^^ expected `&Arc<ProxyPool>`, found `&ProxyPool`
```

I have already tried to create a new Arc and clone of self reference

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Turning arbitrary references into an `Arc` is not possible, after all the owner might not be an `Arc` to begin with.
You can fix that problem in your case by just changing the receiver to be an `Arc<Self>`:

```rust
    async fn get_connection(self: Arc<Self>) -> Result<PooledConnection, ()> {
        loop {
            if let Some(conn) = {
                let mut connections = self.connections.lock().unwrap();
                connections.pop()
            } {
                return Ok(PooledConnection {
                    stream: conn,
                    pool: self,
                });
            }
            // If no connection is available, wait a bit and try again.
            tokio::time::sleep(Duration::from_millis(100)).await;
        }
    }
```

And adjusting the callsites.

I'd prefer taking a `Arc<Self>` over `&Arc<Self>` here since you know you need an owned `Arc` and this way the caller can decide to pass you one they already have or `Arc::clone` it themselves if they want to keep it or only have a reference.